# get menu name for the current displayed page

Tags: menus

I need to get the current menu name/id for the current displayed page so that a different logo can be displayed based on the pages current menu.

I have one site that shows two different clubs, each club has their own logo and the menus on their respective pages is different.

Club 1 has menu 1 and logo 1
Club 2 has menu 2 and logo 2

What is the best way of programming this and is it better to put it in the functions.php file

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're already displaying a different menu, then you've already found a way to differentiate between the pages, so why not apply the logo using the same logic?  Apologies if I'm not understanding.  Can you include your code where you include the menus?

Comment: Tony Djukic : The two menus are selected during the page creation as a dropdown select box within the wordpress features. I'm newish to wordpress and have tried various ways of adding php to the function.php file but haven't had any success.

Comment: So you didn't build the theme then?  It's going to be really tough to provide assistance with the limited information and with a third-party theme.  You'll need to provide your code, etc.